# Reset password not working with custom domains from VF page

Tags: visualforce, community, passwords

I have a VF page which does among other things allows resetting of passwords of users.
I am using  `System.resetPassword(usrid,true)` to send emails to user whose password is been reset.

This functionality works fine in sandbox and i receive the reset emails. But when i move this code over to production and this production system uses a custom domain, this reset doesn't work.

Is there a different way the resetpassword needs to set while using custom domains? 
We are using salesforce communities and the user whose pwd is reset is a community user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect your issue with both related questions you've posted is that there's a `urlFor` setting that I seem to recall is configured either in your portal or in custom settings (sorry, but don't have time to check at the moment, but believe it's in the portal setting) that needs to be changed when moving from sandbox to production.

When you moved your site from the sandbox to production, the `urlFor` setting (Salesforce domain URL address prefix like NA1, NA2, etc. eg: `https://www.NA5.salesforce.com` vs a sandbox prefix like CS1) needs to be changed from your sandbox's configuration URL to the one for your production org.