# INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API

Tags: visualforce, community, passwords

In an extension of one of my earlier questions 
[Reset password not working with custom domains from VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13512/reset-pwd-not-working-with-custom-domains-from-vf-page)

On checking of the debug logs it was throwing out an exception. This page is accessed from salesforce communities with a custom domain. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

> System.UnexpectedException: INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API

```
04:53:50.123 (123669000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[42]|System.resetPassword(Id, Boolean)
04:53:50.123 (123737000)|DML_BEGIN|[42]|Op:resetPassword|Type:User|Rows:1
04:53:50.127 (127614000)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[42]|System.UnexpectedException: INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API
04:53:50.127 (127633000)|DML_END|[42]
04:53:50.127 (127747000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[42]|System.resetPassword(Id, Boolean)
04:53:50.127 (127787000)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
04:53:50.127 (127863000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API
```

Here is the apex code

```
public pageReference changepw() {
    try {
        system.resetPassword(usrId, true);

        usrId='';
        otherMessage = 'An email with the new password has been sent to the user';
    } catch(exception e) {
        otherMessage = e.getmessage();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Do all System methods fail, or just resetPassword? Maybe try calling something simpler, like currentTimeMillis().

Comment: @Prady you got any solution for this?

Comment: @RatanPaul Sorry i dont remember what we did then. Its probably some 5 years back

Comment: ok cool I can understand. I got solution as well cheers

Comment: @RatanPaul Gr8, maybe you could just post the answer here, so others could benefit

Comment: yeah i will....

Comment: thanks @RatanPaul